# Localizable.strings issue with SVN

Tags: iphone, ipad, localization, cvs, localizable.strings

these are the steps i followed to create Localizable.strings file.

1) created a folder called "en.lproj"
2) ran the command from terminal genstrings -o en.lproj Classes/*.m

it generates correct file under "en.lproj".
now my question is how do i add that file to my project. i did drag n drop that file but its not giving me any option to add to repository. 
am i doing something wrong.

Comment: I know it's a bit glib, but one thing you're doing wrong is using CVS. The world has moved on, CVS isn't even in the previous generation of version control systems. Check out Git or Mercurial.

Comment: oh sorry. actually i am using SVN.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question? What I think I'll do is manually import the language.proj folders into my svn.

Comment: no luck yet. i can give a try

Answer (score 1):

The method I use goes something like this:

1. Create the file to be localized (Localizable.strings)
2. Add that file to Xcode directly (no en.lproj folder or anything)
3. Select that file in Xcode, right click, "Get Info"
4. General tab, "Make file localizable"

This way, Xcode takes care of the folder stuff for you, and I would assume take care of the SCM management stuff too.  I personally don't like to use Xcode for SCM, I prefer using an external tool, for separation of concerns, etc.

Comment: but it does not give me an option to commit my changes after modification. and also after my initial checking(add to repository) my team mate didnt get file or English.lproj folder?